# PHP: How to scrape a data from aspx form post method through php

Tags: php

I have an aspx page [here](http://fcainfoweb.nic.in/pms/Average1_web.aspx). The page has a form with a post action:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Average1_web.aspx" id="form1">
```

The result after submitting the form is itself an aspx page (`Report_For_mthly_avg_Zonewise.aspx`).

I need to scrape the data from the result page for all the permutations and combinations of the form inputs. Is there any way that I can get the result of the post method in a php string rather than in the page (`Report_For_mthly_avg_Zonewise.aspx`)?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589160/using-curl-to-submit-retrieve-a-forms-results

Comment: not much idea about curl...but in the link that you sent, where is the relationship between the curl code and the form being defined?

Comment: Just did a quick answer... it should be close to what you need. The array should be your formfieldnames => valuesyouwanttopost

Answer (score 1):

```
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "yourform.php"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('field1' => 'val1','field2' => 'val2','field3' => 'val3','field4' => 'val4'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $result;
```

$result will hold the html code for the page the form lands on after submit... so the page you want to scrape.

Comment: tried using it... but didnt work...blank screen. Relevant lines: 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "Average1_web.aspx"); 
and second one  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('ddltype'=>'Retail','lbxzone' => 'NORTH ZONE','lbxcomm' => 'Wheat','ddlmonth1' => 'January','ddly1' => '2014','rbltype' => 'Average Price Report'));