# PHP Open Information extraction (relation extraction) to retrieve subject verb object triples by loading JAR file and passing arguments

Tags: php, stanford-nlp, triples

I have searched for PHP based information extraction approach but I could not find. Several inquiries by others remain unanswered. For example: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/996885/how-to-extract-triples-text-in-php

I am writing a PHP script to analyse posts on a web forum. I would like to perform Open Information Extraction by extracting the triples (subject-verb object).

It seems hard to integrate NLP libraries with the necessary features in PHP. There are some NLP libraries, but none offer triple extraction (relation extraction). With this feature, I can get closer to understanding and capturing their sentiments. I was hoping to use the ClausIE tool to extract subject-verb-object triples (https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/ClausIEGate/ClausIEGate/). This library can capture who wants to do what, for example, it would help us extract these triple - "I" (subject) "shoot" (verb) "myself" (object) from the sentence "I want to shoot myself".

I have been trying for a week now to call this jar file from within PHP. I think the exec() function can be used. But I don't know how to call the jar file and pass arguments at the same time.

Calling the clausie.jar directly wasnt working as it does not accept arguments. So I used the sample script provided by the library - example.java and compiled it into a jar file, and I am not trying to call that jar file.

I have written some code and am trying to implement code from here but nothing prints out when I try to execute the line that executes the exec function calling the jar file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";

exec('java -jar example.jar I shot Tom' . implode(' ', $theOutput));
//######## Nothing shows up as result 
print($theOutput)

exec("java -jar example.jar 'i kill tom'", $output);
print_r($output); 
// THE ABOVE LINE OUTPUTS Array()
// Then I tried to print the elements of the array, but nothing gets printed

$newLangs = implode($output);
print_r($newLangs);

foreach ($output as $value) {
   print_r ($value);
}

//Also no output in the output file from this line
//exec("java -jar clausie.jar 'I will kill myself' > output.txt", $output);
//print_r($output);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

But this does not work for some reason. Nothing is output. Maybe I am not passing parameters to the clausie.jar in the right way? There is an Example.java in src directory in the ClausIE Code zip file which shows how to pass arguments - buts thats from within Java.

The same jar file executed at the command prompt works.

```
c:\code>java -jar example.jar "I want to kill tom"
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.6 sec].
# CLAUSE DETECTION
#   Dict. copular        : 25 (be, prove, sound, ...)
#   Dict. ext-copular    : 31 (love, be, prove, ...)
#   Dict. not ext.-cop.  : 2 (die, walk)
#   Dict. complex trans. : 15 (set, lay, bring, ...)
#   Dict. ignored adverb : 6 (as, thus, even, ...)
#   Dict. included adverb: 5 (seldom, barely, scarcely, ...)
#   Dict. conj adverbs   : 0
#   Conservative SVA     : true
#   Conservative SVOA    : false
#   Process all verb CCs : true
#   Process non-verb CCs : false
#   Process appositions  : true
#   Process possessives  : true
#   Process partmods     : true
#
# REPRESENTATION
#   n-ary propositions  : false
#   Min. opt. args      : 0
#   Max. opt. args      : 1
#   Lemmatize           : false
#   Appositions verb    : "is"
#   Possessive verb     : "has"
Input sentence   : I want to kill tom
Parse time       : 0.144s
Dependency parse : (ROOT
                     (S
                       (NP (PRP I))
                       (VP (VBP want)
                         (S
                           (VP (TO to)
                             (VP (VB kill)
                               (NP (NN tom))))))))
Semantic graph   : [want/VBP nsubj:I/PRP xcomp:[kill/VB aux:to/TO dobj:tom/NN]]
ClausIE time     : 0.008s
Clauses          : SVO (V: want@2, S: I@1, XCOMP: kill@4)
Propositions     : ("I", "want", "to kill tom")
```

I would be grateful if someone could assist in calling a jar file and passing arguments in PHP.

ClausIE tool online demo - https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/ClausIEGate/ClausIEGate/
Website: https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/ambiverse-nlu/clausie
ClausIE Code: http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/d5/clausie/clausie-0-0-1.zip

Comment: "*There are many errors*" - like what? "*I do not know where to start*" - with the errors? :-) If you search for something like "*submit form with php*" you'll get many answers here on SO, it looks like you've done that and are on the right track, though [using `curl`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4589160/6089612) is maybe more common than `stream_context_create()`.  One thing - `//https://...` is not a valid URL, I expect that is not working?

Comment: Also be careful not to hammer the target page with your requests.  Do they provide an API for machine use like you're trying?  Try not to abuse the resource they are providing.

Comment: I have now vastly improved the question by changing it. I have now included the challenge I am facing with the code I am executing. I would be glad if anyone could guide me.

Comment: "nothing shows up" - what have you tried to resolve that problem? Is this really a PHP problem? Do you receive any output when running this without PHP?

Comment: Since there is no error, I do not know what to resolve - that's why I am asking here.

Comment: I only see this output "My first PHP page"

Comment: Did you try to run the JAR without PHP? Is that working better?

Comment: Yes, I can successfully run the jar file on the command prompt "java -jar clausie.jar". It runs as a process. However, that way I am also not able to pass the sentence as parameter. So I guess my main question is how to pass a sentence as a parameter, in both scenarios?

Comment: If you cannot share the parameters on the prompt, I doubt that this is possible when using PHP in the middle

Comment: Well, there has to be a way. :)

Comment: Then please share how you run the JAR on the shell with the expected behaviour. Add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: "to the clausie.jar" - the code you've recently edited does not call that jar anymore. Also, if you use quotes around the argument when running the jar through the shell, why not also use quotes when you run it through PHP?

Comment: I have edited the question to say that calling the clausie.jar directly wasnt working as it did not accept arguments. So I used the sample script provided by the library - example.java and compiled it into a jar file.

Comment: "I am not trying to call that jar file" - why not? If you got it working when calling the self-generated JAR file, why not use that?

Comment: I added this code --- 
exec("java -jar cie.jar 'i kill tom'", $output);
print_r($output); 
// THE ABOVE LINE OUTPUTS Array()
// Then I tried to print the elements of the array, but nothing gets printed

Comment: Where does cie.jar come from? If calling example.jar on the shell worked, what would happen if you call **exactly that** jar using PHP and not any other one?

Comment: Sorry, cie.jar should have been example.jar